# Using 3rd party libraries with requirejs

Tags: javascript, box2d, requirejs, google-closure-compiler

Hi I trying to organize my code by using requirejs, but I need to use a library that uses google-closure-compiler, the library is box2djs and you can get it from

https://github.com/leonidax/pl.git

I found that the code calls functions such as goog.require()

Hoy can I use this library by using RequireJS?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, you're asking for a pile of hurt.

The closure library and the google dependency model (goog.require, etc) are tightly linked.

You're better moving to use the closure tools everywhere and trying to hack a composite solution.

Answer (score 1):

I did get google closure library and RequireJS to work together. Just make sure the Closure stuff comes before the RequireJS stuff.

```
<script src='../externalJS/requirejs/require.js'></script>
<script src="../externalJS/closure-library-read-only/closure/goog/base.js"></script>

<script>

    goog.require('goog.structs');
    goog.require('goog.structs.PriorityQueue');

    // i just had to make sure that the closure lib stuff came before the requirejs stuff

    requirejs([
        'loaders_parsers/requiredLibrarys',
    ]);
```